# Cancel out of UISearchBar when user taps on view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisearchbar

Does anyone know how to cancel (resign First Responder) out of a UISearchBar when you tap below the search text box and above the keyboard? Can anyone help post some code to handle this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative idea I got from [iphonedevbook](http://www.iphonedevbook.com/), sample code project 04, was to use one big transparent button that lies behind all other controls which does nothing but resign all first responders if tapped. I.e. if the user taps anywhere where there isn't a more important control - which is the intuitive behavior - the search bar and keyboard disappear.

Comment: This is effectively the same as my suggestion above.  It might be a bit simpler to implement.

Comment: Thank you Hauke! Creating the transparent button and handling the touchup event to resign the first responder did the trick.

Comment: One other question I now have is let's say I have a view containing an mkmapview behind that transparent button. How can i can reactivate the map once the searchBar has gone away?

Comment: I guess it's not relevant anymore - but for other who are interested:you can detect tap on the Map using UITapGestureRecognizer, and then you don't need to use a button at all:

UITapGestureRecognizer *taprec = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap)];
    [Map addGestureRecognizer:taprec];

Answer (score 12):

Add a tap gesture in the parent view (of the UISearchbar)

```
[self addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:searchBar action:@selector(resignFirstResponder)]];
```

Comment: This code makes sense, if ```self``` is a ```UIView```. But most of the time, ```self``` is actually a ```UIViewController```, so this should really be ```[self.view addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self.searchBar action:@selector(resignFirstResponder)]];```

Answer (score 3):

I accomplished this by using a UITapGestureRecognizer:

```
UIGestureRecognizer* cancelGesture;

- (void) backgroundTouched:(id)sender {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}

#pragma mark - UISearchBarDelegate

-(void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    cancelGesture = [UITapGestureRecognizer new];
    [cancelGesture addTarget:self action:@selector(backgroundTouched:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:cancelGesture];
}

-(void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    if (cancelGesture) {
        [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:cancelGesture];
        [cancelGesture release];
        cancelGesture = nil;
    }
}
```

The code is a bare, but you can see the intent. When the SearchBar starts editing, you attach a tap gesture recognizer to the view controller's view, and remove it when it stops editing.

There are a couple caveats that you can work around: doing this will make it so if you click anything besides the keyboard or the search bar's text field, the recognizer traps the click -- so if you use the clear, cancel, scope or results button they won't respond correctly.

In my particular scenario, I had a UITableView that was covering the exposed area of the view so I attached the gesture recognizer to it instead of the view controllers main view, isolating the area to which the gesture would respond.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using a hybrid of Hauke's and Beau Scott's approach. There were two problems I ran into using their solutions:

1) If there's anything else on the screen, tapping it won't result in resignFirstResponder being called. For example, if the user taps a button rather than the space around the button, the button will eat the event. Beau Scott's solution addresses this issue, however.

2) Tapping the search bar itself will result in resignFirstResponder getting called. Clearly you don't want the keyboard to disappear when you tap UISearchBar. A small change described below addresses this.

I ended up setting up my view as follows. The parent view has two children - the UISearchBar and a subview which holds the rest of my UI elements. The subview takes up the entire screen below the UISearchBar. Then I used Beau Scott's exact code to add and remove the gesture recognizer, but instead of adding it to self.view I added it to the subview:

```
IBOutlet UIView *gestureRecognizer;
```

...

```
-(void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    cancelGesture = [UITapGestureRecognizer new];
    [cancelGesture addTarget:self action:@selector(backgroundTouch:)];
    [gestureRecognizer addGestureRecognizer:cancelGesture];
}

-(void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    if (cancelGesture) {
        [gestureRecognizer removeGestureRecognizer:cancelGesture];
        [cancelGesture release];
        cancelGesture = nil;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a reference to the search bar.  Let's assume that your controller object has an object reference UISearchBar *theSearchBar, and that you assign it when you create the UISearchBar object.

Next, you need to detect that the containing view has been touched.  The view that is touched "knows", but you need get that information to the controller.  Sadly, Apple didn't provide a simple way to do this, but it's not that hard either.

My solution is to replace the standard UIView that a UIViewController object normally creates with a UIControl, and then make the UIViewController respond to touch events.

**MainController.m**

```
- (void) loadView {
    UIControl *control = [[UIControl alloc] initWithFrame: <desired frame>];
[control addTarget: self action: @selector(touchUpInside) 
             forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
       // or touch down events, or whatever you like
    self.view = control;
    [control release];
}

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    theSearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame: <desired frame>];

    // insert code to finish customizing the search bar

    [self.view addSubview: theSearchBar];
}

- (void) touchUpInside {
    if [theSearchBar isFirstResponder] {
        // grab any data you need from the search bar
        [theSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

**MainController.h**

```
@interface MainController : UIViewController
{
    UISearchBar *theSearchBar;
}
```

Clarification:

There is only a single object -- let's call the class MainController -- which is a subclass of UIViewController.  All of the methods listed above are implemented in MainController.  theSearchBar is declared as a UISearchBar* in the .h file.

Are you defining your view and controller using Interface Builder?  If so, I suggest you learn how to NOT use it -- once you get into the kind of tricks we are discussing here, it becomes more of a hindrance than a help -- I don't use it at all, ever.

Comment: How do I get the reference to the searchBar from the touchUpInside event? I have touchUpInside in the viewcontroller class containing the searchbar.

Comment: You mean, in order to invoke resignFirstResponder?  You already have it if you saved it as a reference when you created it.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Is the above code supposed to be in a separate view controller from the one where I created the search bar? Also why do you create a UIControl instead of a UISearchBar in your loadView routine?

Comment: Yes, you are confused, and probably because I didn't put in enough code for you.  I will edit my response.

Comment: Thanks for more details. I tried following your update very specifically but now I'm getting the error:
error: 'searchBar' undeclared (first use in this function). FYI, searchBar is the name of the UISearchBar *searchBar declared in my viewDidLoad event. Do I need to declare searchBar globally?

Comment: Not globally, but in the MainController.h file (or whatever you call it).  I will put in just a bit more above to show you what I mean; however, if you REALLY don't understand this, I think you need to read the documentation in a bit more detail.

Comment: I've already done all the things you mentioned. Now, when I build and run, it says loading more than a hundred thousand stack frames. The debugger breaks to some machine assembly and the simulator displays a black screen. When i comment out your loadView routine above, it runs fine. Please advise.

Comment: It has to do with how you are assigning self.view in loadView.  I need to double-check the syntax -- please give me a bit to do so.

Comment: Duh.  I made a silly mistake.  viewDidLoad has no parameters -- it's only those like viewDidAppear, etc. that have "animated" as a parameter.  Try fixing as shown above.

Comment: I tried, but am still getting an exception. I'm using iphone sdk 3.0.

Comment: Okay, at this point, I need to see your actual code.  Otherwise, there isn't much I can do.

Comment: I'd prefer not to post my email here.  Would it really be so bad to post just the methods that are involved?

Answer (score 0):

@Gia Dang's answer is the simplest, but I don't subclass the `UIView`, only the `UIViewController`, so my call is *slightly* different. Also, since I don't know the overhead for actually calling `resignFirstResponder`, I prefer to check first. It's more code, but since all of this is done on the main thread (which can slow down the UI), I'd rather check first.

```
@implementation MyController : UIViewController {
@private
    UISearchController *_uiSearchController;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // add tap on view to resign the responder if we're in the middle of typing in the search
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(closeKeyboardIfNeeded)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
}

- (void)closeKeyboardIfNeeded {
    if (![_uiSearchController.searchBar isFirstResponder]) {
        return;
    }
    [_uiSearchController.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

As for the other answers, be careful about constantly recreating objects. There is always a performance hit, whether it's the creation itself or the garbage collection through *ARC*, and these things will slow down your main thread. Depending on what you're doing also on the main thread, it may have a significant performance impact.