# Using tap gesture to dismiss keyboard, rest of screen no longer works

Tags: ios7

I have a UITableViewController that contains a UISearchBar in one of its cells. Following examples here, I put a addGestureRecognizer in my viewDidLoad to capture taps outside the searchBar and calls resignFirstResponder on the search bar so the keyboard is dismissed.

However, this seems to be trapping *all* taps, the other items in the tableView no longer respond.

This is odd, because I have the identical code (cut and pasted) in another screen, a UIViewController, and it works fine there. The user can continue clicking on other objects just fine.

Any ideas? I suspect this is a simple view hierarchy issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh, it seems the first version I wrote shouldn't work either. The key is to enable the tab gesture only when the searchBar is entered, and then disable it again when you exit. This question has all the code:

[Cancel out of UISearchBar when user taps on view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288322/cancel-out-of-uisearchbar-when-user-taps-on-view)